# Proper punctuation for include, but are not limited to

Tags: commas

I am writing my thesis and am struggling with punctuation for this sentence:

> The set of primitive actions these agents can perform include but are not limited to move, attach and clear.

First I thought adding commas would do the trick, i.e.:

> The set of primitive actions these agents can perform include, but are not limited to, move, attach and clear.

But this looks and reads weird, so I figured I'd add a semicolon, i.e.:

> The set of primitive actions these agents can perform include, but are not limited to: move, attach and clear.

But this also *feels* wrong. What is the actual proper way of punctuating this sentence?

Comment: 'The set of primitive actions these agents can perform include – but are not limited to – _move_, _attach_, and _clear_.' Though 'The set of primitive actions these agents can perform include, but are not limited to, _move_, _attach_, and _clear_.' is not too hard to construe. The dashes demarcate well, but are perhaps too heavy-duty here.

Comment: Thank you, that feels better to read I think.

Comment: You can also use a a comma after "include" and a colon after "limited to". _...can perform include, but are not limited to: etc._

Comment: I'd say it's more important to write the sentence clearly than to write it correctly, since there are several ways to do both. It just demands a degree of subjective judgment.

Comment: Semantically (and idiomatically), it would be much better to say that the *actions* are **movement**, **attachment**, and **clearance**. (Or perhaps **moving**, **hitting**, and **clearing**.) Listing verbs in this construction, rather than nouns, doesn't really work.